# Upgrade postgre sql 9.4.5 from 9.3.10 (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) Dockerfile

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Is there any way I can upgrade my psql to latest in my OS version which is 14.04.3 LTS?
I'm using Dockefile for installation to a several packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postgres sql official image is based on debian:jessie.

You can try and [reproduce its 6.4.5 Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/ed23320582f4ec5b0e5e35c99d98966dacbc6ed8/9.4/Dockerfile) in yours (based on ubuntu 14.04) and see if you can install postgres 9.4.5 that way.

Comment: Aside on debian:jesse, there's no other way? Thanks

Comment: @DenContre The idea is to replicate that Dockerfile, but starting with your OS for your container, to see if it is possible to install postgres 6.4.5. That would allow to have your own postgres image (installed on ubuntu: let's name that image `mypostgres4.5`) that you can use in your current Dockerfile project (replacing `FROM ubuntu:14.04` by `FROM mypostgres4.5`)